# How to decrypt the state token returned by createToken() returned by StateTokenBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using [Google OAuth2 Library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) while building a Google Apps Script project. In that I am passing a state parameter created via createToken function of [StateTokenBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder) . I am getting the state parameter passed on to my callback function via redirect-uri. However, I don't know how to decrypt this state parameter. I had created it using "withArgument" function and would like to access some of the parameters I had passed in earlier.

Could you please help on how to decrypt it? I don't know what encryption method was used to be able to decrypt it. And the documentation doesn't talk about decryption at all.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to decrypt it, unless `/usercallback` end point was used, in which case, it's automatically decrypted. If not, you cannot use the state token at all.

Comment: Thanks. There is another issue with state token being passed even though usercallback end point is used. I worked around by using getUserProperties(). Thanks.

Comment: It'll be helpful to others if you add it as a answer. See [answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TheMaster pointed, one can't decrypt state token. It gets automatically decrypted if it is passed on with /usercallback.

In my case that was not happening (state token was not being passed in spite of /usercallback being used), so I worked around it by passing state token as part of the redirect-uri, so that I don't get 400 error for the callback not being called.

Then I accessed the values that I was trying to access via state token, via setting and retrieving values using getUserProperties()